# why the cumsum of pdf and cdf are different for scipy.stats.norm?

Tags: python, scipy, cumsum, cdf

I tried to compare the results for the values of cdf from cumsum of pdf and cdf of scipy.stats.norm. Why these are different?

```
#%%
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm


x=np.arange(10)

m=np.mean(x) # mean of x
v=np.var(x,ddof=1) # variance of x
s=np.std(x,ddof=1)  # standard deviation of x

x1=np.linspace(min(x),max(x),10)
y=norm.pdf(x1, loc=m, scale=s)
y=np.cumsum(y)
y=y/y[-1]
print(f'y is : {y}')

y1=norm.cdf(x1, loc=m, scale=s)
y1=y1/y1[-1]
print(f'y1 is : {y1}')

y is : [0.04835861 0.12317281 0.22695357 0.35603744 0.5        0.64396256
 0.77304643 0.87682719 0.95164139 1.        ]
y1 is : [0.07365228 0.13295909 0.21954114 0.33299004 0.46641076 0.60724152
 0.74066224 0.85411114 0.94069318 1.        ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cumsum` of the `pdf` is only an approximation of the `cdf`.

Recall that the `cdf`, F(x), is the integral of f(x) (the `pdf`) from negative infinity to x. The `cdf` for `scipy.norm` is an analytic function so will be (nearly) exact.

The cumulative sum in your implementation has two issues. 1) You aren't integrating from negative infinity, but instead integrating starting from your lower bound in `x1` which is only about `1.5sigma` away from the mean, so there is some error introduced there. And 2) `cumsum` effectively assumes that the function value is constant across the `dx` value in your `x1` array, which is not true either. If you choose a larger number of points in your `x1` array you will get closer agreement between the two functions (though the error in point 1) will still be there.